# "Expected Identifier" error in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have made a very basic iOS app which displays the time in a label on viewDidLoad.
I'm getting an Expected Identifier error on this line of code :

```
NSString *myTime = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:[*myDate]];
```

Here'e the ViewController.m file :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize timeLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSDateFormatter *myDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [myDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm a"];
    NSDate *myDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSString *myTime = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];
    [timeLabel setText : myTime];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Made some additions. The code compiled but now I'm getting a Thread 1:SIGABRT error.
The application doesn't load on the Simulator and the error comes.
Here's the line of code which is giving the error in the main() :

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

Yup, I didn't link it. Its working now. Thank you all!

Comment: Don't just remove *, remove also the [ ] surrounding myDate.

Comment: i just test your code with     NSString *myTime = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];    and it gives me time.

Comment: Have you linked timeLabel in Interface Builder? this code works for me too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

remove * like this

```
NSString *myTime = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:mydate];
```

Comment: I think it's better to use ``[NSDate date]`` instead of ``[[NSDate alloc] init]`` because there is no need to retain the date in the code provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `NSString *myTime = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :     `NSString *myTime = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];`

Answer (score 0):

SIGABRT error occurs when an exception is encountered while the application is run. 
This may be due to a memory exception or any other runtime error.

You can try to clean and build you project. If it persists, check the target debugger console .

Answer (score 0):

I'm with SKM17 `NSString *myTime = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:mydate];` 
but just make sure there is something in mydate with

```
NSLog("mydate = %@",mydate);
```

if it still doesn't appear. Logging is always a good idea to check that values are where they are supposed to be :D